# HTML5 app - avoid downloading every time?

Tags: html

I am getting ready to develop an HTML5 application. It's not a game but for sake of discussion let's call it a simple game.

Let's say I host the app/game on my web server.

User clicks to my web server, downloads the game (may take several seconds, to a minute?), sends a high score to the server, is put on a leaderboard.

Tomorrow the user comes back and wants to play again. Does the user need to download the game again?

Or, is this where the cache manifest can be used to prevent a re-download?

And, if they don't have to download the whole thing everytime, how can I force a download if I want an update to the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Browser Cache**

If you do nothing the browser will download and cache copies of any static files your application uses the first time it encounters them. This is automatic and the files are stored in the browser cache.

The next time the file is requested by your application the browser will send a request to the server and include the date and time of the copy it already has. If the file has changed on the server a new copy will be provided. If not, the server will respond with a 304 code - Not modified and the browser will use its existing copy. In this case a request is always sent to the server, but the file is only downloaded if it's changed.

You can configure your server to add an expiry date to static files. The browser still caches the file locally as before, but on the next access the browser checks the expiry date sent with the copy it already has. If that date hasn't passed no request is sent to the server. Now, you've saved the round-trip time of every request that refers to a cached file.

**A manifest**

A manifest works differently. When the initial file is downloaded the cache maifest is read and every file listed in it (apart from some specific exceptions dependent on the content of the manifest) is downloaded and store in the application store. Often, this requires the user to give permission for it to happen.

On subsequent access the manifest file is requested from the server. If the manifest hasn't changed nothing more is done and the application is loaded and run from files stored in the application store.

if the manifest has changed *in any way* then the new manifest is used to download and update the existing application store files.

**Pros and cons**

*Browser cache*

- For

  - Automatic & transparent
  - Largely maintenance free
  - Many files need not be downloaded or checked
- Against

  - Distribution of new files may be delayed
  - Application must run online

*Manifest*

- For

  - Application can run offline
  - Manifest gives good control over update distribution
- Against

  - User permission often required to use the application store
  - Additional maintenance is required to update the manifest appropriately.

Comment: Thank you, this gives me a great starting point to research more. Cheers~